# running python from cmd gives "Access is denied" error

Tags: python

My office laptop has Anaconda 3 with python 3.5 installed. I was able to run python scripts from cmd, but recently when i type python or pip in cmd , it simply says "Access is denied."
I have tried many things, like giving full permission to the anaconda folder.
One point to mention here is i am able to run python from spyder, but unable from CMD. Also pip or conda install from cmd gives the same error of "access is denied". 
someone had mentioned it may be an anti-virus issue. I tried to look into "On-access Scan properties" of McAfree Virus Scan console, but i feel since its my company laptop i am not able to add any folders as exclusions. Thanks in advance for any pointers or help.

Comment: What's the operating system?

Comment: Are you try run as admin?

Comment: @Ywapom, windows 10 operating system. ...

Comment: @Saeed Bolhasani Since its a company laptop, do not have admin rights, although i did temporarily had taken admin rights and tried opening cmd as administrator and running python, but got the same error